# How do you delete Minikube hostpath directory from host using xhyve?

Tags: macos, kubernetes, minikube

I'm using the PersistentVolume functionality for sharing VM directories with Pods. For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: psql-data-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/psqldata
```

But I can't figure out how to delete the directory from the host VM so that I can reset the data. Minikube persists the `/data/` directory across VM reboots, but doesn't document where it's storing it.

If you `kubectl delete PersistentVolume psql-data-disk` it doesn't delete any of the contents in the directory itself, it just deletes the K8s resource.

I'm using the `docker-machine-driver-xhyve` driver installed via brew on OSX Sierra.

Answer (score 5):

Ugh, I hadn't known about the `minikube ssh` command to get into the VM. So I just went in there and deleted the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you and Add some solution which i experienced
persistant volume(pv) mounted to hostpath can't be deleted because of 'permission denined'
And then if you do nothing in your minikube, you can login in root user.
`login` and input 'root'